# Create S-57 chart on ARCGIS containing only shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-10.4, esri-production-mapping, s-57

I have a requirement where a shapefile/files needs to be converted to S-57 ENC chart for use on ECDIS system. I am not working in GIS domain so dont necessary understand all technical bits and bobs involved.

Till now I have done following steps.
I have downloaded ARCGIS + Maritime Charting and Production mapping (Desktop 10.4.1) on trial basis. Please note that I dont have any ENC data to work on.

I have created a new file Geodatabase in Acrmap, Imported XML workspace data/schema from file "Nautical_chart_template_GX.xml".

I have carried out  steps to load the shapefiles under "UserdefinedfeaturesA", create AOI (using Feature builder) under "PL_ENC_AOI" setup scale to 10000000.

Start "New Nautical Product" wizard, which works without any errors.  But when creating ENC "Export Nautical product". The I am getting "Error - Nothing found 10000000" during Export process. Export log does not give much details.

I dont have any data inside other layers. Just PL_ENC_AOI to define AOI and "UserdefinedfeaturesA" with 3 sublayers contains data.

Can anyone guide me the right way to approach this issue.